# when does $h(x)^Tx>0$ result in $\int_{0}^x h(y)^Tdy>0$?

Tags: inner-products

Let $h(x)\in R^n$, and $x\in R^n$ satisfy 
$$h(x)^Tx>0,~~\forall x\neq 0$$
and 
$$h(x)^Tx=0,~~~\text{when}~~~ x=0$$

is it true that $\int_{0}^x h(y)^Tdy>0$ for all $x\neq 0$?

comment: when n=1, the answer is yes.

Comment: Sorry, could you rewrite the integrand and the variable of integration?

Comment: is there a $y$ missing in the integrand?

Comment: Is the integral a notation for a path integral on the form $\sum h_i(y)dx_i$ along the segment from $0$ to $x$?

Comment: There is no y missing in the integral. To Jonathan Y. Yes: $\sum h_i(y)dy_i$